# How to change upstart order, Start network after fstab?

Tags: xen, ubuntu-12.04, upstart

In ubuntu 12.04, I want to change order; I want to mount all from fstab before running network (i have /etc/network/interfaces on other partition). How to do it? This is my fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620 0  0
/dev/xvda1       none           swap    sw              0        0
/dev/xvda3      /               ext3    ro,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/xvda2      /home           ext3    defaults                0       0 
none            /etc            overlayfs lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/home/.etc 0 0
/home/.var/run /var/run         none    defaults,bind   0       0 
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   nosuid,noexec   0       0
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,noexec   0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/init/network-interface.conf try changing the line that reads

```
start on net-device-added
```

into

```
start on net-device-added and filesystem
```

If that does not work, have a look at /etc/init/mountall.conf and see which other events are emmited, and substitute `filesystem` with one of those other events.